# Check duplicate value in select before append

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to check duplicate value of select box before append options if first select box value all ready in append list stop new duplicate append.

[here is jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58418x2r/2/)

```js
$(function () {
    $("#addtoption").bind("click", function (){
          var div = $("<div />");
          div.html(GetTransferOpt(""));
          $(".trnlistopt").append(div);
    });
});

function GetTransferOpt(value) {
    var digit = $('#digit').val();
    var trtyp = $('#type').val();
    var trsdet = $('#number').val();
    return '<span class="dig">'+digit+'</span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="trnsto">'+trtyp+'</span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="trnsop">'+trsdet+'</span>';
}
```

```css
.trnlistopt { padding:20px 0 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>If first select box value all ready append </p>

<select name="digit" id="digit">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>

<select name="type" id="type">
  <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="number" id="number" value="">

<input type="button" id="addtoption" value="Add">

<div class="trnlistopt"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep an array. on click push option to array. next time check that option is present in that array using `indexOf()` if it is not there add it else don't add

```js
$(function () {
    added_options = [];
    $("#addtoption").bind("click", function (){
          var div = $("<div />");
          console.log(added_options);
          if(added_options.indexOf($('#digit').val())>-1){
               alert("error");
               return false;
          } else {
             added_options.push($('#digit').val());
             div.html(GetTransferOpt(""));
             $(".trnlistopt").append(div);
          }
    });
    
    $("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
        
                $(this).closest("div").remove();
                
                
                added_options.splice(added_options.indexOf(this.id),1);// step to remove from added options
                
    });
});

function GetTransferOpt(value) {
    var digit = $('#digit').val();
    var trtyp = $('#type').val();
    var trsdet = $('#number').val();
    return '<span class="dig">'+digit+'</span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="trnsto">'+trtyp+'</span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="trnsop">'+trsdet+'</span> &nbsp; <span class="remove" id="'+digit+'">remove</span>';
}
```

```css
.trnlistopt { padding:20px 0 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>If first select box value all ready append </p>

<select name="digit" id="digit">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>

<select name="type" id="type">
  <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="number" id="number" value="">

<input type="button" id="addtoption" value="Add">

<div class="trnlistopt"></div>
```

Comment: it's working at the time of add values but once i add value and remove it from add list  and if re add it show's error 

check working link  https://jsfiddle.net/58418x2r/6/

Comment: @zero now i updated my answer check now. you have to remove item from added_options also. use splice to remove. to remove button give id that should be the value of digit. so that when you click on remove button get the id use that id to remove from added_options

Answer (score 0):

Track with array and check all properties are equal or not , if not equal add to html

```js
var options=[];

$(function () {
    $("#addtoption").bind("click", function (){
          var div = $("<div />");
          var divHTML=GetTransferOpt("")
          if(divHTML!=1)
             div.html(divHTML);
          $(".trnlistopt").append(div);
    });
});

function GetTransferOpt(value) {
   var digit = $('#digit').val();
    var trtyp = $('#type').val();
    var trsdet = $('#number').val();
     var option={
      digit : $('#digit').val(),
      trtyp: $('#type').val(),
      trsdet : $('#number').val()      
      }
      for(i=0;i<options.length;i++){
        if(option.digit==options[i].digit)
         if(option.trtyp==options[i].trtyp)
         if(option.trsdet==options[i].trsdet)
         return 1
      
      }
      options.push(option)
    return '<span class="dig">'+digit+'</span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="trnsto">'+trtyp+'</span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="trnsop">'+trsdet+'</span>';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>If first select box value all ready append </p>

<select name="digit" id="digit">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>

<select name="type" id="type">
  <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="number" id="number" value="">

<input type="button" id="addtoption" value="Add">

<div class="trnlistopt"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
    $("#addtoption").bind("click", function (){
          var div = $("<div />");
          div.html(GetTransferOpt(""));
          $(".trnlistopt").append(div);
    });
});

function GetTransferOpt(value) {
    var digit = $('#digit').val();
    var stop = false;
    
    // loop trough all results and check if already exists
    $('.trnlistopt .dig').each(function(index, element){
      if(parseInt($(element).text(), 10) === parseInt(digit, 10)) {
          return stop = true;  // stop foreach loop and set stop to true
      }
    });
    
    if(stop) {
        return; // do nothing if digit is found
    }

    var trtyp = $('#type').val();
    var trsdet = $('#number').val();
    return '<span class="dig">'+digit+'</span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="trnsto">'+trtyp+'</span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="trnsop">'+trsdet+'</span>';
}
```

```css
.trnlistopt { padding:20px 0 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>If first select box value all ready append </p>

<select name="digit" id="digit">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>

<select name="type" id="type">
  <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="number" id="number" value="">

<input type="button" id="addtoption" value="Add">

<div class="trnlistopt"></div>
```